# Installing Firebase pod error Invalid Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, installation, firebase

I'm trying to run this...

```
platform :ios. '9.0'
use frameworks!

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
```

but I keep getting this on the pod install

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '('
platform :ios. '9.0'
                ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

Comment: Have you, cough, tried updating CocoaPods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the line

platform :ios. '9.0'

to

platform :ios, '9.0'

ie changing your period after ios to a comma